# Why am I getting a ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know a similar question has been asked previously, but I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting this error.

I'm using the below code to create a new column with the row being marked as an outlier if the 'price' falls within the upper limit, 'price_h2' and lower limit, 'price_h1'

`df_test['price_outlier'] = np.where( df_test['price_h1'] <= df_test['price'] <= df_test['price_h2'],'normal','outlier')`

Help much appreciated!

Comment: You need to be more specific when asking questions on S.O. For example, It is best to try to produce a "Reproducible" question with a small amount of data (shown for others to use) and any other relevant code. So that others can try it too. And either the same error or not.

Comment: Ok, will keep in mind for future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because numpy arrays doesn't support the syntax:  ***a < x < b***

You need use parenthesis to separate both clauses ***(a < x) & (x < b)***:

```
df_test['price_outlier'] = np.where((df_test['price_h1'] <= df_test['price']) &\
                                    (df_test['price'] <= df_test['price_h2']), 
                                    'normal', 'outlier')
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian - that's where I was getting confused

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that pandas chooses to throw an error if you attempt to broadcast operations on multi-element boolean Series, as it is inherently ambiguous as to what the behavior should be.

> pandas follows the NumPy convention of raising an error when you try to convert something to a bool. This happens in an if-statement or when using the boolean operations: and, or, and not. It is not clear what the result of the following code should be:

See [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-truth) for more information on this behavior.

As for how you can get your desired behavior to work; keep in mind that you can assign a column to a dataframe using many different datatypes (lists, dicts, ndarrays, etc.). Therefore, a simple way you can sidestep the problems of series comparisons is to use a list comprehension.

```
df_test['price_outlier'] = [a <= b <= c for a, b, c in zip(df_test['price_h1'], df_test['price'], df_test['price_h2'])]
```

Comment: Cheers sudo-rushil - especially for the explanation. It's a smart solution to the problem